# how do you test for opera mini in your dev environment

Tags: testing, browser, opera

Most of my users are using opera mini to visit my website and there are some things which doesn't work under opera mini. How can I simulate opera mini in my laptop/dev environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Opera's Mini Simulator](http://www.opera.com/developer/opera-mini-simulator).

You may also want to have a look at some of the answers to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594450/debug-on-opera-mini), especially some of the articles from dev.opera.com they link to.

Keep in mind that Opera Mini itself doesn't render the page; it receives a compressed version of the page rendered on one of Opera's servers.