# Are there any debugging tools for the Opera Mini mobile browser?

Tags: browser, developer-tools, opera-mini

For the desktop Opera browser we have Firebug to debug the webpage (debugging the HTML structure, CSS properties, etc.). Is there any kind of similar debugging tools that can I install in Opera Mini?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to debug on Opera Mini?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594450/how-to-debug-on-opera-mini)

Comment: Firebug is a Firefox add-on. I guess you are talking about Firebug Lite or Opera's built-in DevTools.

Answer (score 7):

You can use special commands(enter command into address panel):

**server:console** - Show console and javascript error for current page

**server:source** - Display the current page's source code

**server:reset** - clears all cookies

**config:** - Open the the Power User Settings menu

**opera:cache** - Displays the size and URL of cached pages and images

**about:** - Displays information about the Opera Mini server

**debug:** - Displays a page listing many Opera mini server and client properties. The "Host:" field tells you which Opera Mini server you are currently connected to.