# How to debug a web application running on Opera on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, web, opera

My web application has an issue. It breaks while running on Opera + iPhone. How to debug such combination?

I've looked into many online posts and posts that are similar to mine,
but those posts are either inaccurate or outdated, like 
[How to debug on Opera Mini?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594450/how-to-debug-on-opera-mini)

It is easy to reproduce the bug. I am sure i can address the issue if I can observe what happened to the application during the process.

It is a really a margin case. I would be lucky and happy is someone had dealt with it before.