# XMLHttpRequest() is not working in Opera mini

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, xmlhttprequest, opera-mini

I just Trying to make an asynchronous project with XMLHttpRequest. it works well on other browsers but not working on Opera Mini Mobile Browser. now tell me how can I fix this.
Code:

```
function runxml(){
  var xmlhttpr;
  var setup = document.getElementById("setup");
  if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttpr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
     // for IE8 and Earlier
    xmlhttpr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttpr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(this.readyState == 4 || this.status == 200) {
      setup.innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttpr.open("GET", "file.txt", true);
  xmlhttpr.send();
}
```

Comment: please post the error message displayed in console.

Comment: how can I view console log in mobile phone??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594450/how-to-debug-on-opera-mini. May help